# How to build an Android NDK app on FAT

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, file-permissions, fat

I'm using the `FAT32` file system in Linux (as I need to also access it on Windows and OSX), but when I compile with `ndk-build` I get the error

```
install: setting permissions for `./libs/armeabi/libfoo.so': Operation not permitted
```

I gather it's trying to set more restrictive permissions for the newly-created library, however you cannot change permissions on files in a FAT partition.

Is there any workaround, such as flags in the toolchain to stop it trying to change files' permissions? Or perhaps something in Linux to fake a successful permission change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try running the NDK build under [fakeroot](http://fakeroot.alioth.debian.org/), although I've never tried that and not sure it is applicable.

A much better solution IMHO would be to use ext3 and install drivers to access ext3 file system from Windows and MacOSX:

You can use [Ext2 IFS for Windows](http://www.fs-driver.org/) driver to access the files from Windows and [extfsx or fuse-ext2](https://superuser.com/questions/17205/free-filesystem-drivers-for-ext3-on-os-x-leopard) to do the same from MacOSX

Comment: Spent a large amount of time trying to get ext3 working on OSX and Windows, and found that file permissions don't translate well. I'll have to try NTFS under OSX (as it already works under Windows and Linux)